# How to classify the digits in a specific number?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a program that demonstrates the use of the arithmetic sequence, which asks for the starting term of the user, the difference between the terms, and how many terms does the user want to generate. The code and a demo down below:

```js
var t0, difference, boxedNums, numOfTerms, redCircle, redTriangle, redRectangle, blueCircle, blueTriangle, blueRectangle;
redCircle = "<img src='imgs/negativeOne.png'>";
redTriangle = "<img src='imgs/negativeTen.png'>";
redRectangle = "<img src='imgs/negativeHundred.png'";
blueCircle = "<img src='imgs/one.png'";
blueTriangle = "<img src='imgs/ten.png'";
blueRectangle = "img src='imgs/hundred.png'";

function genTn() {
    reset();
    t0 = document.getElementById("t0").value;
    difference = document.getElementById("d").value;
    numOfTerms = document.getElementById("tn").value;
    var tn;
    document.getElementById('buildButton').style.display = 'none';
    for (n = 0; n < numOfTerms; n++) {
        tn = t0 * 1 + difference * n;
        setTimeout(buildNextOne, 3000 * n, n, tn);
    }
    setTimeout(showButton, 3000 * numOfTerms);
}

function buildNextOne(n, tn) {
    var insert = '<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">'
    insert += '<span class="boxed center">'
    insert += 't<sub>' + n + '</sub>'
    insert += '<span class="tn">' + tn + '</span>'
    insert += '</span>'
    insert += '</div>'
    document.getElementById("boxArea").innerHTML += insert;
    
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(tn);
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}

function showButton() {
    document.getElementById('buildButton').style.display = '';
}

function reset() {
    document.getElementById("boxArea").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
}

#equation {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10%;
}

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#formula {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

span {
    display: block;
}

.boxed {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: beige;
}

.tn {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Assignment 10a2</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="formula">
        Formula: <br>
        t<sub>n</sub> = t<sub>0</sub> + d*n <br>
        <br>
        t<sub>0</sub>
        <input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" id="t0" class="slider">
        <br>
        d
        <input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" id="d" class="slider">
        <br>
        n
        <input type="range" min="1" max="20" value="10" id="tn" class="slider">
        <br>
        <button id="buildButton" style="display:''" type="button" class="btn btn-warning"
            onclick="genTn()">Generate</button>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="boxArea">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="10a2.js"></script>
</body>
```

However, I wanted to add some images to represent the number; for example, a circle represents one, a triangle represents ten, and a square represents hundred. The desired result is like this:
[image: Desired result]

I am not sure how to take that number had been generated and check the digit, classify it to either one, ten, hundred, etc. , and then insert the corresponding images. Is there a way to do it?

This is how the pictures are represented:

```
redCircle = "<img src='imgs/negativeOne.png'>";
redTriangle = "<img src='imgs/negativeTen.png'>";
redRectangle = "<img src='imgs/negativeHundred.png'";
blueCircle = "<img src='imgs/one.png'";
blueTriangle = "<img src='imgs/ten.png'";
blueRectangle = "img src='imgs/hundred.png'";
```

Comment: Do you want to get the individual digits? `let digits = { one : number % 10, ten : (number/10)%10, hundred:(number/100)%10 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add following function

```
function getPicsRepresentOfNumber(number) {
  var totalHund = 0,
      totalTens = 0,
      totalOnes = 0,
      returnHtml = '';

  totalHund = Math.abs(parseInt(number/100));
  var diffAfterRemovingHund = number % 100;
  totalTens = Math.abs(parseInt(diffAfterRemovingHund/10));
  totalOnes = Math.abs(parseInt(diffAfterRemovingHund % 10));

  for (var i = 0; i < totalHund; i++) {
      returnHtml += number < 0 ? '-H' : 'H';
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < totalTens; i++) {
    returnHtml += number < 0 ? '-T' : 'T';
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < totalOnes; i++) {
    returnHtml += number < 0 ? '-O' : 'O';
  }

  return returnHtml;
}
```

I used
-H for negative hundred

H for positive Hundred

-T for negative Tens

T for positive Tens

-O for negative ones

O for positive ones

For Your working you need to replace

'-H' with redRectangle,

'H' with blueRectangle,

'-T' with redTriangle,

'T' with blueTriangle,

'-O' with redCircle,

'O' with blueCircle

Working Demo

```js
var t0, difference, boxedNums, numOfTerms, redCircle, redTriangle, redRectangle, blueCircle, blueTriangle, blueRectangle;
redCircle = "<img src='imgs/negativeOne.png'>";
redTriangle = "<img src='imgs/negativeTen.png'>";
redRectangle = "<img src='imgs/negativeHundred.png'";
blueCircle = "<img src='imgs/one.png'";
blueTriangle = "<img src='imgs/ten.png'";
blueRectangle = "img src='imgs/hundred.png'";

function genTn() {
    reset();
    t0 = document.getElementById("t0").value;
    difference = document.getElementById("d").value;
    numOfTerms = document.getElementById("tn").value;
    var tn;
    document.getElementById('buildButton').style.display = 'none';
    for (n = 0; n < numOfTerms; n++) {
        tn = t0 * 1 + difference * n;
        setTimeout(buildNextOne, 3000 * n, n, tn);
    }
    setTimeout(showButton, 3000 * numOfTerms);
}

function buildNextOne(n, tn) {
    var insert = '<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">'
    insert += '<span class="boxed center">'
    insert += 't<sub>' + n + '</sub>'
    insert += '<span class="tn">' + tn + '</span>'
    insert += getPicsRepresentOfNumber(tn)
    insert += '</span>'
    insert += '</div>'
    document.getElementById("boxArea").innerHTML += insert;
    
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(tn);
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}

function getPicsRepresentOfNumber(number) {
  var totalHund = 0,
      totalTens = 0,
      totalOnes = 0,
      returnHtml = '';
   
  totalHund = Math.abs(parseInt(number/100));
  var diffAfterRemovingHund = number % 100;
  totalTens = Math.abs(parseInt(diffAfterRemovingHund/10));
  totalOnes = Math.abs(parseInt(diffAfterRemovingHund % 10));
  
  for (var i = 0; i < totalHund; i++) {
      returnHtml += number < 0 ? '-H' : 'H';
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < totalTens; i++) {
    returnHtml += number < 0 ? '-T' : 'T';
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < totalOnes; i++) {
    returnHtml += number < 0 ? '-O' : 'O';
  }
  
  return returnHtml;
}

function showButton() {
    document.getElementById('buildButton').style.display = '';
}

function reset() {
    document.getElementById("boxArea").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
}

#equation {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10%;
}

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#formula {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

span {
    display: block;
}

.boxed {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: beige;
}

.tn {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Assignment 10a2</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="formula">
        Formula: <br>
        t<sub>n</sub> = t<sub>0</sub> + d*n <br>
        <br>
        t<sub>0</sub>
        <input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" id="t0" class="slider">
        <br>
        d
        <input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" id="d" class="slider">
        <br>
        n
        <input type="range" min="1" max="20" value="10" id="tn" class="slider">
        <br>
        <button id="buildButton" style="display:''" type="button" class="btn btn-warning"
            onclick="genTn()">Generate</button>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="boxArea">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="10a2.js"></script>
</body>
```